# NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.dll For NHibernate 3.2

Tags: nhibernate, linfu-dynamicproxy

Where can I find the latest version of NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.dll that is compiled against NHibernate 3.2?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From 3.2, NHibernate ha its own embedded proxy generator: there are nо more need of NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.dll or NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll and I don't think they are supported any more.

I think you have to download the last supported source of NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.dll source, and try to compile it against the 3.2.

Comment: So when configuring the NHibernate Session factory, what type should I set as the ProxyFactory?

Comment: Are you using web/app.cofig or are you configuring NHibernate via c# code?

In the first way you have to specify "codedom" (for CodeDOM based one), "lcg" (for Lightweight one) or a custom provider.

Via c# code, you have to specify an istance of `NHibernate.Bytecode.CodeDom.BytecodeProviderImpl`, `NHibernate.Bytecode.Lightweight.BytecodeProviderImpl` or a custom one.

Comment: Ok, so This didn't work for me, what I had to do was use the following proxy factory: NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory

Answer (score 28):

in NHibernate 3.2 you do not need NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.dll because NHibernate 3.2  implements the proxy by itself. so we need modify the config like as:

```
<property name=”proxyfactory.factory_class”>NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate</property>
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, try removing the proxyfactory.factory_class line from your config file altogether.